# Jquery-Ui : Highlight effect inside iframe using Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

I am trying to do the highlight effect using Firefox.

The element is inside of an iframe.
My code works with Chrome but not with Firefox.

To catch the content, I use :

```
var iframeContent = $(window.frames[0].document.documentElement);
var elem = $(iframeContent).find("#something");
```

Then, I use the effect like that :

```
$(elem).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
```

I call my effect after every "onLoad" event. Once iframe and document are loaded.

How can I do ?

Thanks.

EDIT : I added an example : https://jsfiddle.net/yr1h9fdz/10/

Comment: Can you check with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11801977/2968762

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. :/